# Error on import to Craft production db

Tags: mysql, import

I just copied my database across from local server to production server. I used Craft's control panel to create a backup. Then I used Sequel Pro to import this into the live server.
I got this error:

> [ERROR in query 121] The query length of 4327045 bytes is larger than max_allowed_packet size (4194304).

I clicked on 'Continue' and all looks OK on my live site.
Can someone suggest what this might mean? Should I worry? What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Your MySQL configuration has its [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) config setting set to the default 42M (4194304).

There's a query that executed for database backup that is slightly larger than that (about 44M).

You'll need to increase that value in your MySQL config or ask your host if they can do it for you if you want to import the backup without any errors.

Comment: Thanks Brad. Could this larger than expected query be a symptom of a problem in my configuration or templates?

Comment: Most like just a server side MySQL configuration issue.